# Is it necessary to register website on facebook, twitter or LinkedIn for og: tags for gatsby react app?

Tags: reactjs, metadata, gatsby

I have addded all og tags and twitter tags in my react website but facebook and linkedIn website debugger cannot get the tag. Is it necessary to register or claim domain website on Facebook and LinkedIn? And in twitter I got Error like this,

```
INFO:  5 metatags were found
ERROR: No card found (Card error)
WARN:  this card is redirected to https://www.website.com/
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Card Validator (from Twitter)](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) to check your metatags. Assuming you copied my snippet from the [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776334/how-to-make-image-link-for-my-website-like-this-https-website-com-image-png-in):

- Ensure that you are adding `twitter:card` and `twitter:image`, your output should be:

  ```
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://startcrowd.club/images/startcrowdimage.jpg">
  ```

  Source: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image
- Your final output, should look like:

  ```
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimesbits" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nickbilton" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/08/a-twitter-for-my-sister/" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="A Twitter for My Sister" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="In the early days, Twitter grew so quickly that it was almost impossible to add new features because engineers spent their time trying to keep the rocket ship from stalling." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2011/12/08/technology/bits-newtwitter/bits-newtwitter-tmagArticle.jpg" />
  ```

Make sure that your `robots.txt` is not blocking Twitter's bot.

Other resources:

- [Twitter-Card Meta Tag Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480011/twitter-card-meta-tag-issue)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I got the issue. It is regarding meta tags position. check this https://marcomelilli.com/posts/gatsby-react-helmet-og-meta-tags-are-not-recognized